# Как сделать, чтобы программа не закрывалась во время простоя?

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-ndk, java

Я написал программку, открывающую доступ к файловой системе ОС Android через сеть. Проблема в том, что хоть она и должна работать постоянно, она, тем не менее, закрывается через какое-то время (если не активна).

Как вообще сделать, чтобы программа на **Java** не закрывалась и работала постоянно?

И, полагаю, тот же вариант подойдет для **C++** программы написанной с помощью **JNI**?

Comment: о, троян пишете?

Comment: кто закрывается? программа в сон уходит? или соединение?

Comment: С чего тут вирус? Доступ к файловой системе полезная штука, щас отлаживал программу не мучаясь с подключением телефона к компу для заливки, а загружал через wifi на sdcard.

Я пока не очень понял, что происходит. У меня закрывается tcp соединение с андроидом. В нормальной ситуации, когда программа может быть завершена? Сейчас все заработало безупречно и не удается воспроизвести ошибку. А до этого постоянно отваливалось. Вполне может быть, что это глюк программы и андроид тут не причем.

Answer (score 3):

Здравствуйте. Есть пара идей как это можно сделать:

1. В сервисе (если вы его используете) прописать, что бы он загружался сразу же при запуске системы.
2. В программе мониторить состояние сервиса.
3. В программе, во время вызова событий `OnDestroy` и `OnStop`, сделать что бы она сворачивалась.

P.S. 3-ий способ сильно кушает батарейку! Кусок кода смогу предоставить, но позже. Если я где то не правильно высказался, то поправьте.

Код:

1) ServiceBootStart.java

```
public class ServiceBootStart extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
          Intent serviceLauncher = new Intent(context, ServiceExample.class);
          context.startService(serviceLauncher);
          Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "Service loaded while device boot.");
        }
      }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <receiver android:name=".service.ServiceBootStart" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
                   <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                    </intent-filter>
              </receiver>
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`
```

2) Ну по этому пункту, то тут уже на
    сколько вашей фантазии хватит. Я
    например писал в файл весь лог
    действий сервиса, потом программа
    считывала на каком этапе был сервис,
    на каком действии остановился, где
    вылетела ошибка и т.д. ну а дальше
    делал логику действий в определённых
    ситуациях (но это всё оч.
    геморойно). Можно проще сделать,
    просто просматривать список
    запущенных программ, сервисов и
    сравнивать названия пакетов с
    названием пакета вашего сервиса, ну
    и делать после этого определённые
    действия.

Код проверки, работает ли сервис:

```
public boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceClassName){
       ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
       List<RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

      for (RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : services) {
          if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceClassName)){
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
   }
```

3) Код, вместо выхода из приложения, просто его свернуть:

```
@Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {// обрабатываю нажатие на кнопку "назад"
         if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

                moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
         }
         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
     }
```

P.S. 3-ий пункт точно не помню, вроде бы так оно делается, просто нет исходников под рукой чтобы посмотреть.

Comment: Еще есть вариант воспользоваться AlarmManager'ом, пытаться запустить сервис скажем каждые пять минут, если упал.

Comment: А не могли бы по первому и второму еще код предоставить? А то мне тоже безумно интересно).

Comment: Да, понял, что надо делать в виде сервиса. Не подскажете, где почитать, как его писать? Класс Service я использую, но так понимаю, что там нужно указать системе, что программа не должна закрываться. И как вообще выключить программу, какой функцией?

Comment: mikelsv
Любая статья про сервисы, вот те которые мне когда то помогли http://blog.divenvrsk.org/2010/09/android.html?spref=tw и http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html
Как сделать что бы программа не закрывалась я написал и предоставил код (3-ий способ). 
Эммм...последний вопрос немного не понял, вам же не надо закрывать программу, ну та ладно, вот один из способов: `system.exit(0)`

Comment: Ага, почитал статьи сделал сервис. Долго мучался с потрясающим глюком: если сделать конструктор в классе сервиса программа будет падать. Кстати вот самый лучший пример сервиса: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html Он сразу работает. Правда его еще нужно немного поправить... Решил немного отжечь: http://mikelsv.livejournal.com/7832.html .


У меня осталась одна проблема по поводу сервисов. Мой сервис запускает сишный код, через нативную функцию, которая запускает поток. И есть такое подозрение, что через некоторое время поток убивается. Что можно почитать на эту тему?

Comment: Жгёте однако)) 
По поводу сервиса: не знаю, мои знания про сервисы на этом заканчиваются, ищите литературу про сервисы и способы про то как сделать сервис не убиваемым. Когда мне нужна была не убиваемая программа, то я просто делал, что бы она не закрывалась и всё, мне этого хватало.